# Laravel 4 : Shows errors in vendor folder

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm new to Laravel. I have installed Laravel 4 using the composer. I didn't have any troubles during the installation besides the missing mcrypt extension issue. I have managed to install mcrypt and reinstall laravel 4 successfully.

But after that my NetBeans IDE shows lots of errors the laravel my vendor folder. Most of them caused by the syntax errors.

see the examples:

1. BlocklessStatement.test file

   Blockless statements for if/for/etc

   ---

   if ($a) $A;
      elseif ($b) $B;
      else $C;
2. kmyacc.php.parser file

   #if -t
      class #(-p)_Debug extends #(-p)
      #endif
      #ifnot -t
      class #(-p)
      #endif
3. closure.test

   Closures

   ---

Most of the .php files are having a word before the `<?php` tag like Closures, Declare, Header, Blockless...etc. In the middle of the .php files I can see "-----" blocks which cause most of the errors. Netbeans can't understand them.

I really want to remove those errors. How can I fix them? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

these are not real errors... they may be templates or config files etc. and not php files (thus you are getting parsing errors).

They can safely be ignored, however if you *really* want to get rid of them, you can add their file extensions in the ignored files of your project properties (i.e. `*.test` using examples above) and those files will not even appear in your project's source tree in NetBeans any more.

Comment: @NeverBeenToSchool no problem... did it answer the question?